# How to use Google Cloud Datastore Statistics

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I use Google Cloud Datastore stats object (in Python ) to get  the number of entities of one kind (i.e. Person) in my database satisfying a given constraint (i.e. age>20)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query objects have a nice [`count`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_count) method which you could use:

```
qry = Person.query(Person.age > 20)
n_people_older_than_20 = qry.count()
```

Here I assume you're using the `ndb` queries (i.e. `Person` is an `ndb.Model` subclass).  I'm sure that there's an equivalent for the older `db` interface as well ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't, that's not what it's for at all. It's only for very broad-grained statistics about the number of each types in the datastore. It'll give you a rough estimate of how many Person objects there are in total, that's all.